# Living with a zero-income partner, what offers the best Tax considerations?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction

If I am living with a partner, currently unmarried, who cannot work what would yield the best tax situation in the US:

1. Marrying them and filing as Married - Joint Filing with just the one income to declare?
2. Filing with them as a dependent?

Which one would generate the best possible return?

Comment: Marriage carries with it a lot more than just lower taxes.  I would absolutely not marry someone just to lower my taxes.

Comment: This gets more complex because that can also impact other things such as  government benefits, health insurance...

Comment: @RonJohn, it is worth noting that we have been together for a good number of years and have a family together. We make enough in income that we shouldn't be getting and don't need the government benefits and I have good enough health insurance to add them to. Ultimately, the point has come to which is better on tax forms.

Comment: There are a lot of details that can factor into this since US taxes are not straightforward. But assuming your income does not change, a quick estimate can be made by looking look at the 1040 instruction tax tables to see what income XYZ pays when single or married. Also, when married (filling jointly) the standard deduction doubles versus filing single. Giving your income last year, see what is the lax liability is for married filing jointly does if you double your deduction.